# NHibernate's out of the box features

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-sql, entity

How does NHibernate provide out of the box features as compared to the other OR/M tools available like ADO.NET entity framework and LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some feature comparisons:

- [NHibernate, Entity Framework, active records or linq2sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/)
- [NHibernate vs EF 4](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/01/Comparing-NHibernate-EF-4)
- [NHibernate vs Lightspeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732105/lightspeed-vs-nhibernate)